# Request parameter in Express router

Tags: javascript, express, express-router

I'm having some trouble accessing request parameters in express router.

My `server.js` file has this:

```
app.use('/user/:id/profile', require('./routes/profile');
```

And this is in my `./routes/profile.js` file:

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.params.id);
}
```

But the console log prints `undefined`.
I'm new to express and feel like I'm missing something basic about how routing works.
Can someone please help me out?

Here is my full `server.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.use('/user/:id/profile', require('./routes/profile'));

app.listen(5000, () => console.log('Listening'));
```

Here is my full `profile.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params.id);
  res.status(200).send('In profile route');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: What URL are you visiting? Can you print out the entirety of `req.params`? Can you send the full `profile.js` file?

Comment: @Aplet123 I'm trying to hit ```http://localhost:5000/user/112/profile```. Theres not much anything in ```profile.js``` really other than the require statements and ```module.exports = router```.

Comment: @Aplet123 yes I am able to do ```console.log(req.params)``` but that is also empty

Comment: Well then do you mind sharing all this information?

Comment: @Aplet123 edited my question to include full files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL parameters are not exposed to routers. You have a couple of options here:

1. Parse `req.originalUrl` to get the user id (not recommended). `req.originalUrl` isn't affected by the router's mount point and will remain as `/user/112/profile` or whatever url you visited.
2. Add some middleware to expose the id (recommended). Your new route statement will end up looking like this:

(Now you can use `req.userId` in your `profile.js`)

```
app.use('/user/:id/profile', function(req, res, next) {
    req.userId = req.params.id;
    next();
}, require('./routes/profile'));
```

3. Change the mount point from `/user/:id/profile` to `/user`, then edit your router to listen on `/:id/profile` (not recommended).

Comment: I have seen a lot of examples where people use stuff like option 3, where they have parameters in the router. Why is that approach not recommended?

Comment: I'd assume that `/profile` isn't going to be the only thing under `/user/:id`, so it's better to not mount to the entirety of `/user`. Also, approach 2 results in generally cleaner code.

Comment: @AneeshDandime Glad I could help you!